# "Take a look at our Uniform, Workwear and PPE solutions." or "Take a look at our Uniform, Workwear and PPE solutions."

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

the following statement is going onto a mail to customers and we are having a debate on if it should be uniform or Uniforms?

> Take a look at our new website today to learn a little more about our industry leading **Uniform,** Workwear and PPE solutions.

or

> Take a look at our new website today to learn a little more about our industry leading **Uniforms**, Workwear and PPE solutions.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 uniform type? Then Uniforms.  The other two already look to be plural to me.

Comment: I think it should be uniforms (plural) regardless, as the sentence is likely to be parsed <(uniforms), (workwear) and (ppe solutions)> rather than <(uniform[s], workwear and PPE) solutions>.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the word "solutions" to apply to each of the items? If that's what you mean you should probably re-write it along these lines.

"Take a look at our new website today to learn a little more about our industry leading solutions for Uniforms, Workwear, and PPE."

Or do you mean "solutions" to only apply to PPE? Then it should be plural.

"Take a look at our new website today to learn a little more about our industry leading Uniforms, Workwear, and PPE solutions."

PPE is "personal protective equipment." In my industry this means things like hard hats, safety shoes, eye protection, radiation dose badges, chemical protection equipment, high voltage protective equipment, fall arrest equipment, and several other such items. So it's quite reasonable that "solutions" applies only to them.